# Why can I have an OpenGL shader class, but not a VAO class?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I have been fiddling around with making a game/rendering engine, and I have found that I can have a class for a shader object, but if I wrap a VAO in a class, it won't render.

The shaders return no errors, and the VAO and shaders are valid OpenGL objects.

**UPDATE**

The problem is this line:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(arrFVertex), arrFVertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

As @BDL suggested in the comments, I thought about it and I realized, it should be:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * intNumVertex * 3, arrFVertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

**UPDATE 2**
In response to being put on hold, here is a Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example:

```
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

SDL_Window *window = NULL;
SDL_GLContext openGLRenderer;
bool bolRunning = true;
int intGLVersionMajor, intGLVersionMinor;

GLfloat arrFVertex[] = {
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // Top Right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // Bottom Right
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // Top Left 
    
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // Bottom Right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // Bottom Left
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f   // Top Left 
};
GLuint intVAO;
GLuint intVBO;
GLuint intShaderAttribPosition;
GLuint intShaderProgram;
GLuint intNumVertex = 6;

void loadShaders(const char *strVertexShaderSource, const char *strFragmentShaderSource) {
    intShaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    
    GLuint intVertexShader;
    intVertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(intVertexShader, 1, &strVertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(intVertexShader);
    
    GLuint intFragmentShader;
    intFragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(intFragmentShader, 1, &strFragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(intFragmentShader);
    
    glAttachShader(intShaderProgram, intVertexShader);
    glAttachShader(intShaderProgram, intFragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(intShaderProgram);
    
    glDeleteShader(intVertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(intFragmentShader);
}

void buildVAO(GLfloat *arrFVertex) {
    intShaderAttribPosition = glGetAttribLocation(intShaderProgram, "f3Position");
    
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &intVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(intVAO);
    
    glGenBuffers(1, &intVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, intVBO);
    
    glVertexAttribPointer(intShaderAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid *)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(intShaderAttribPosition);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(arrFVertex), arrFVertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("GSEngine",
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              640, 480,
                              SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    
    if (window == NULL) {
        printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }
    
    openGLRenderer = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, openGLRenderer);
    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
    
    loadShaders("#version 330 core\n\
                in vec3 f3Position;\n\
                void main() {\n\
                    gl_Position = vec4(f3Position, 1.0);\n\
                }", "#version 330 core\n\
                out vec4 f4Color;\n\
                void main() {\n\
                    f4Color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n\
                }");
    
    buildVAO(arrFVertex);
    
    while (bolRunning) {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                bolRunning = false;
            }
        }
        
        SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, openGLRenderer);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        glUseProgram(intShaderProgram);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, intNumVertex);
        
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }
    
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &intVBO);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &intVAO);
    glDeleteShader(intShaderProgram);
    
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(openGLRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wrapping your code in a class or not makes no difference as long as all the correct OpenGL commands are called. I think you should really try to make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of expecting us to download your whole repository. Besides, when you change the code in there, this questions becomes worthless for future readers.

Comment: I was planning on leaving that repo alone, and I am not sure how to make it more minimal, but I will try.

Comment: OK, fair enough. You mention that it doesn't work when you wrap your VAO in a class. Does it mean that you tried a version without a VAO class and it worked? If so, it might be useful to look for differences in that code.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it without a class wrapping the VAO, and it renders just fine. Also, I have looked several times for differences, I will again now to see if I missed something. Do you want an example of it working without the VAO class?

Comment: Updated repo to remove window class, still broken.

Comment: People debugging code in an external repo is really not the way SO works. You'll have to extract the critical code, and post it here. As a side effect, once you do that, chances are that you'll see the problem yourself. I couldn't resist taking a quick peek, and it's a **very** obvious problem once you just read through the code.

Comment: Check out what `sizeof(arrFVertex)` returns.

Comment: @BDL, THANK YOU VERY MUCH. You should make an answer saying that the proper code is: `sizeof(GLfloat) * intNumVertex * 3`. The reason the code was like that was because I was using a `GLfloat[]` before I encapsulated it in a class and used a `GLfloat *`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi, I understand that I should post relevant code, but there is a lot of code I felt could be the problem, I will post the code I now know to be the problem for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the VAO, but with the VBO. Since you pass a pointer to the constructor:

```
void GSMesh::build(GLfloat *arrFVertex, GSShader *shader, int _intNumVertex)
{
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(arrFVertex), arrFVertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

`sizeof(arrFVertex)` = `sizeof(GLfloat*)` which is the size of the pointer, not the size of the array pointed to. The correct code will look like this:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
             sizeof(GLfloat) * _intNumVertex * 3, arrFVertex,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

In general I have to add, that this is not the way how questions should be asked on SO. It would have been good if you would have included at least the relevant parts of the code in your question.

Comment: The only reason I made a github repo, was so that I didn't make the question super long, and also, I wasn't sure what function specifically was the problem, but you have shown me, and it is super obvious now.

Comment: By answering them, you encourage people to ask questions like this.

Answer (score -1):

Despite what the spec says, with some drivers you must enable the shader before you can get the location of an attribute or uniform. This may be what is causing your problems.

In your code that would mean in your GSMesh::build method adding:

```
shader->use();
```

Before:

```
intShaderAttribPosition = glGetAttribLocation(shader->intShaderProgram, "f3Position");
```

Personally if the version of OpenGL that you are using has support for [Vertex Attribute Indexes](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29#Vertex_shader_attribute_index) I'd use them instead.

In the vertex shader you could have something like:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 tex_coords;
```

And then in your mesh class all you need is:

```
struct Vertex
{
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec2 tex_coords;
};

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, position);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, tex_coords));
```