# OpenGL C++: Struct wrapper for VBO won't initialize members

Tags: c++, opengl, struct, constructor

I am pretty new to OpenGL, and have been going through some online tutorials to get used to the API. I understand that the creation of a VBO goes as such:

```
GLuint vboID;                                                        
glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verticesArray), verticesArray, GL_STATIC DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
```

And, prior to declaring any given VBO, I create a VAO and bind it. At this point in time, I'm working by making one VBO per one VAO.

I want to make some wrapper tools on top of the API, just so that the things like creating VBOs and VAOs become more convenient.

I've began to create a struct that will, in its constructor, take an array of vertices and create a VBO from them. I've named it "triVBO", just because I'm creating only "GL_TRIANGLES" objects right now.

A "triVBO" struct is defined as follows:

```
struct triVBO {
GLuint ID = 0;
const void* data = (void*)0;
GLsizeiptr verticeCount = 0;
GLsizeiptr triCount = 0;

triVBO(const void* _data) {
    //VBO generation
    GLuint vboID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(_data), _data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    //do our assigning
    data = _data;
    ID = vboID;
    verticeCount = (sizeof(data) / sizeof(GLfloat)) / 3;
    triCount = verticeCount / 3;
}
};
```

Everything runs and compiles fine. However, the problem lies in the assignment of the "verticeCount" and "triCount" members.

As you can see in the constructor, the parameter is a "const void*", which I used because, upon checking the type of the third parameter for "glBufferData()", the third parameter being the array you pass in to the macro and thus the array that I would be trying to pass in to my constructor, I saw it was a "const void*", and I figured that I should use the same type that works for the macro.

I've laced some DEBUG macros that I made throughout the constructor and in the main program, which I've removed from that sample so that it's easier to read. When I run the program with those DEBUG macros in it, this is what I get.

When I call this:

```
triVBO tv_pyrVBO(pyramidVerts);
DEBUG("pyramidVerts: ", pyramidVerts);
DEBUG("tv_pyrVBO.data: ", tv_pyrVBO.data);
DEBUG("tv_pyrVBO.ID: ", tv_pyrVBO.ID);
DEBUG("tv_pyrVBO.verticeCount: ", tv_pyrVBO.verticeCount);
DEBUG("tv_pyrVBO.triCount: ", tv_pyrVBO.triCount);
```

The console prints this:

```
pyramidVerts: 00007FF603EFC4C0
tv_pyrVBO.data: 00007FF603EFC4C0
tv_pyrVBO.ID: 2 
tv_pyrVBO.verticeCount: 0
tv_pyrVBO.triCount: 0
```

From what I can tell, the "data" member, which, in the constructor, I have attempted to assign the array "pyramidVerts", is being assigned properly, because the addresses are the same. Also, the code for the buffer generation and binding works because "ID" is correctly assigned a value of 2 (I have some other VBOs in the program already, that's why it isn't 1). It's just that the "verticeCount" and "triCount" members, whose calculations you can see in the constructor, aren't being assigned properly, as both of them have a value of 0, but with this specific array they should have values of 18 and 6, respectively.

What is the error? Am I using the wrong types to pass around the arrays or hold the information for the "verticeCount" and "triCount"? Is there something in the OpenGL API that I'm missing or using incorrectly that's causing it to not be assigned? Am I making a super obvious mistake of C++ or programming in general? I have searched for hours and I could not come across a stackoverflow or quora or cplusplus answer that really answered my specific question.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated, and any extra GL tips you would like to throw in are welcome as well. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I have an OpenGL shader class, but not a VAO class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343272/why-can-i-have-an-opengl-shader-class-but-not-a-vao-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's just that the "verticeCount" and "triCount" members, whose calculations you can see in the constructor, aren't being assigned properly
>
> Am I making a super obvious mistake of C++ or programming in general?

Yes. `sizeof` doesn't work that way. Take another parameter defining the size of the input and use that instead or, better, take in an `std::vector` or some other standard container that knows its size.

I'd recommend getting familiar with basic C++ concepts before you dive into wrapping OpenGL API, as doing that properly will require a certain knowledge of both the language and the API you're using.

Comment: Thanks! I though I could use sizeof in that fashion because it works when I use it that way outside of the struct, when I just generate the buffers without any kind of wrapper. I did try using vectors from the standard but they didn't work just right with the other code I have setup. I'll try taking in a param for the size to see what happens. Thanks for the advice, I'll make sure I'm brushing up on my underlying skills in the language alongside any API learning.